# Call and run a jupyter notebook from Excel using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, xlwings

In the company I work at, we have just started experimenting with the migration of several computation-heavy projects from Excel to Python. In this process, we have discovered `xlwings` and the power it can bring to the integration of Excel and Python.

Several of our projects include reading in input data from Excel worksheets, doing some background calculations, and then outputting the results to different sheets in the same workbook. From the 
[example projects](https://www.xlwings.org/examples) on the `xlwings` website, I know it's possible to replace VBA macros (which we used so far) with Python, while keeping the Excel front-end.

However, my co-workers, who are primarily financial experts and not programmers, really like the interactivity of `jupyter` notebooks and would appreciate it if they could work in them during the modeling phase of the projects (rather than switching to PyCharm all of a sudden).

All in all, the ideal workflow would look like this for us:
Inputting from Excel sheets, doing some modeling and model calibration in Python through `jupyter` notebooks, running some tests, then if we're at a final stage, then outputting to Excel. A key constraint is that the end-users of our models are used to the VBA-like functionality (eg. *Run* buttons in Excel).

So my question is the following:
**Is it possible to call and run a `jupyter` notebook from Excel as it was a `.py` file (ie. through the `RunPython` function)?** This way, I assume that we could avoid the intermediate step of "converting" the models from `.ipynb` to `.py`, not to mention having two code versions of the same model.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Is there a way to run shell commands inside Excel? Because you can execute notebooks using `nbconvert` (see [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html)) or `papermill` and avoid the conversion. As an aside, Jupyter in your toolchain might be useful to that conversion to notebook to python and back again to only need one file actually kept.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with xlOil (disclaimer: I wrote it).  The relevant docs are [here](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xlOil_Python/Jupyter.html).

The summarised procedure is: install xloil

```
pip install xloil
xloil install
```

Then edit `%APPDATA%\xloil\lxloil.ini` to add a reference to `xloil.jupyter`.  Then in an Excel cell type

```
=xloJpyConnect("MyNotebook.ipynb")
```

Where you have "MyNotebook.ipynb" loaded in a local jupyter kernel.  Then you can execute code on the kernel with:

```
=xloJpyRun(<result of connect func>, "{} + {} * {}", A1, B1, C1)
```

Or watch a global variable in the kernel with:

```
=xloJpyWatch(<result of connect func>, "variable_to_watch")
```

Or you can add a decorator `@xloil.func` to functions defined in the kernel to make them appear as Excel worksheet functions.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://github.com/luozhijian/jupyterexcel with using 'def'. That creates functions callable in Jupyter.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: To follow on that, if you want or need to stay with the `RunPython` both `nbconvert` and `papermill`, that I referenced in a comment to the original question, can be called within Python code via API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies!

We started experimenting with `nbconvert` as @Wayne advised, and basically wrote a small wrapper .py code that can be called in the Excel macro via `RunPython` and that runs the specified notebook as-is. In the notebook, interaction between Excel and `jupyter` (eg. reading parameter data in from Excel and outputting values from `jupyter` to Excel) is handled by `xlwings` in turn.

I'm not sure it is the most optimal solution concerning execution speed though. However, in our case it works just fine and so far we haven't experienced any additional overhead that would hinder user experience.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this is what you want https://towardsdatascience.com/python-jupyter-notebooks-in-excel-5ab34fc6439

PyXLL and the pyxll-jupyter package allows you to run a Jupyter notebook inside of Excel and seamlessly interact with Excel from Python. You can also write Python functions in the notebook and call them from Excel as a user defined function or macro.

From the article:

"""
It used to be an “either/or” choice between Excel and Python Jupyter Notebooks. With the introduction of the PyXLL-Jupyter package now you can use both together, side by side.

In this article I’ll show you how to set up Jupyter Notebooks running inside Excel. Share data between the two and even call Python functions written in your Jupyter notebook from your Excel workbook!
"""

If the above link doesn't work you can also find it here https://www.pyxll.com/blog/python-jupyter-notebooks-in-excel/

[image]

Comment: Beware: PyXLL is paid software.